# How to pass error messages between Grails controllers?

Tags: grails, groovy, error-handling, controller

I'm trying to pass an error message from a grails controller to a grails error controller in order to display an error message in the HTTP response, but I'm not sure what parameter is holding the error message in the error controller.

**URLMappings.groovy**

All 500 errors are mapped to ErrorsController

```
"500"(controller: "errors", action: "serverError")
```

**GenericController**

```
def {
  try{
    //do some work
  }catch(Exception e){
    response.sendError(500, e.getMessage())
  }
}
```

**ErrorsController**

```
def serverError = {

  render( how can I access the exception details here?? )

}
```

I need to access the exception in the ErrorsController so I can output it to the HTTP response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual way to pass short informational messages between controllers is to place it in the flash scope.  For example:

```
def myAction = {
    try {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        flash.message = e.message
        response.sendError(500)
    }
}
```

In this particular case, though, why are you catching the exception?  If you let the exception fall through, grails will automatically generate a server error and call the "500" mapping.  In your error controller, the exception will be available as `request.exception`.

Comment: I've noticed that `flash.message` sometimes displays twice; first for the initial request, and again on the next request; to address this I'm using `request.message` instead, begging the question: what's the point of flash message?

Answer (score 0):

In your **ErrorsController**:

```
def serverError() {
    render request.getAttribute('javax.servlet.error.message')
}
```

renders the message from `e.getMessage()`.